# Unable to have anaconda fully uninstalled

Tags: python, bash, anaconda

I need to uninstall anaconda completely. [I have followed the instruction on this website](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall):
but after that, when i key in `conda list, conda --version` commands in mac bash, it still outputs results as if anaconda is still in my system
how can I check if I have uninstalled all anaconda-related files completely?

the output of `conda --version` is:

```
conda 4.4.7
```

and when I run `$ which python`, I get:

```
/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python
```

when I run `$ python -V`, I get:

```
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
```

Comment: deleting the folder anaconda should solve your problem

Comment: I have. and now in my home directory, when I type "cd ./anaconda", there is no such a profile. yet everything, including the path, the python version, the atom, the jupiter notebook all work in the same way as anaconda were still there.

Comment: and I have tried to empty my .bash_profile, which I heard is a place where I can set up my $PATH, but when I do echo $PATH in terminal, the outcome remains to be :/Applications/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Applications/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS

Comment: well, the path gave you a hint as to where your anaconda folder is. follow  the path and remove them

Answer (score 0):

Since the output of your `$ which python` was `/Applications/anaconda3/bin/python` I would try removing the `/Applications/anaconda3/` folder as well as any relevant references from your `$PATH` file. That should remove Anaconda.